# The negation of this proposition

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

Suppose $p(x)$ is a proposition about a real variable $x$ in the interval $(0,1)$.

Let $P$ be the proposition
$$\bigg(\exists x_0\in(0,1), p(x_0)\bigg)\implies\bigg(\forall x\in(0,x_0), p(x)\bigg) .$$
Is the negation of $P$ the proposition
$$\bigg(\exists x\in(0,1), \text{not }p(x)\bigg)\implies\bigg(\forall x_0\in(x,1),  \text{not }p(x_0)\bigg) ?$$

Comment: Your statement $P$ is likely incorrectly translated: what's the actual scope of $x_0,$ and is the first instance of $x$ really meant to be free?

Comment: Sorry I corrected!

Comment: Still wrong, I suspect: the $x_0$ in the consequent still appears free. Btw the commas in the translations are unnecessary.

Comment: This is what I mean by $P$:  If there exists $x_0$ between 0 and 1 such that $p(x_0)$ holds, then $p(x)$ also holds for all $x$ such that  $0<x<x_0$. What is the negation of $P$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **OP's above comment:**
>
> This is what I mean by $P$:
>
> If there exists $x_0$ between 0 and 1 such that $p(x_0)$ holds, then
> $p(x)$ also holds for all $x$ such that  $0<x<x_0$. $$\bigg(\exists x_0\in(0,1), p(x_0)\bigg)\implies\bigg(\forall x\in(0,x_0), p(x)\bigg).$$

This translation is still wrong: as I pointed out, the $x_0$ in the consequent still appears free (and doesn't depend on the $x_0$ in the antecedent). The correct translation is this: $$\forall x_0\in(0,1)\bigg(p(x_0)\implies \forall x\in(0,x_0) \;\; p(x)\bigg)$$ or, equivalently, $$\forall x_0\in(0,1) \;\; \forall x\in(0,x_0)\bigg(p(x_0)\implies p(x)\bigg).$$

And its negation is this: $$\exists x_0\in(0,1)\;\;\exists x\in(0,x_0)\bigg(p(x_0)\;\;\text{and} \;\; \text{not }p(x)\bigg) .$$

> Is the negation of $P$ the proposition $$\bigg(\exists x\in(0,1), \text{not }p(x)\bigg)\implies\bigg(\forall x_0\in(x,1),  \text{not }p(x_0)\bigg) ?$$

This proposition does not at all negate the erroneous $P$ (nor the correct $P$). If you require any clarification, leave a comment below.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by wrong translation. Suppose $a$ is a positive constant. I claim that if there exists $x_0\in(0,1)$ such that $2^{x_0}<a$, then for all $0<x<x_0$ we have $2^x<a$. What is the correct translation of this?

Comment: @M.Rahmat For all $x_0\in(0,1),\;\big[$  if $2^{x_0}<a,\;$ then for all $x\in(0,x_0),\;\;2^x<a\big].\quad$ (square brackets added for emphasis).  To understand my Answer, It's important that you actually try making sense of whether my 2 (equivalent) suggestions actually meaningfully match your desired proposition.  And that you carefully compare the exact differences between your $P$ and the one(s) I offered.

Comment: @M.Rahmat A couple of obliquely-related observations to illustrate the function of of parentheses:
$$3(4)+5\;\neq\; 3(4+5)$$

$$\big[\exists x A(x)\big]\Rightarrow B \;\; \equiv \;\;\forall x \big[A(x)\Rightarrow B\big].$$ And to elaborate on the first line of my Answer: your original P is equivalently written as $$\bigg(\exists y\in(0,1), p(y)\bigg)\implies\bigg(\forall z\in(0,x_0), p(z)\bigg).$$